# Match everything in a string after the 3rd '/'

Tags: regex, match

I have two different forms of a string:

```
https://anexample.com/things/stuff
```

and

```
https:///things/stuff
```

I need a regular expression that will match everything in the string after the 3rd slash, no matter the syntax.  Once it hits the 3rd slash, the rest of the string is matched.  I have found a bunch of examples, but I can't seem to tweak the right way to get it to work.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your attempt please.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: ^(?:[^/]*\/){3}([^/]*)  That was one I was trying, but I think I am over complicating it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
^[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/(.*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: (+1) for the nice gfx ;)

Comment: @griffin The credit belongs to https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:[^\/]*\/){3}(.*)$
```

And use matched group #1

In javascript:

```
var s = 'https:///things/stuff';
m = s.match(/^(?:[^\/]*\/){3}(.*)$/);
// m[1] => things/stuff
```

Comment: Be careful, the '/' at the start and end aren't part of a regular expression, but delimiters of the same.

Comment: @griffin: Thanks, to avoid confusion I removed regex delimiters.

Comment: Upvoted - you reached the same solution as I did, but I had to reiterate a few times to get there ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PCRE, and that you won't have newlines in your string:

If the 3 slashes can be at any position (like your first example):

`^[^/]/[^/]*/[^/]*/(.*)$`

This could also be expressed as

`^(:?[^/]*/){3}(.*)$`

Using positive lookbehind, you could use the following, which should only *match* what you want instead of putting it into a capturing group:

`(?<=^(:?[^/]*/){3}).*$`

Any needed escaping due to used delimiters is left as an exercise to the reader of course ( if you use `/` as a delimiter, you have to escape all `/` in the expression, like `\/`)

And there's probably a million other alternatives, depending on what exact needs you have besides the ones you mentioned.

Comment: That second one was basically what I was trying, but it is matching the entire string for some reason when I try it in gskinner.  The line I am using is this:

jms://localhost:6000,anotherhost:6000,thirdhost:6000/TD/arandomstring

or have the same thing but with jms:///TD/arandomstring

It should only return /TD/arandomstring but it just matches the whole line for some reason

Comment: of course it does, you need to use the first returned group, not the match. if you don't want to match the whole thing, you can do positive lookbehind. wait a second for me to add something to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, however I'm writting it without any testing, but it should look for three sections of any character any number of times followed by slash and then catch last section which is everything until line end - you can of course change delimiter to whitespace or whatever.

```
^.*/{3}(.*$)
```